# sql server integration service

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.
how to avoid this error practically while import data from excel

Comment: In the absence of more information, [JFGI](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Text+was+truncated+or+one+or+more+characters+had+no+match+in+the+target+code+page)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this could be caused by the fact that you have data that is too long in your source file compared to the field it is going into, the data is in different formats (source to destination), or something else in general like this.  However, since you mentioned that it is coming from Excel, you might want to try this solution too, which works only for Excel:

Set your package to run in 32-bit mode.  Click on `Project` on the top menu and select `Data Imports Properties`.  Click on `Configuration Properties` -> `Debugging` and set the `Run64BitRuntime` to `false`.

This solution sometimes works for Excel projects, but it is an outside shot.  If it doesn't work, try look at the data formats and fields in the source (and what they are being imported as).